# Can this conditional logic be condensed?

Tags: if-statement, logic, conditional-statements

I'm looking for someone(s) to cross-check my logic here.

I have come across a conditional of the following format in some code, and I'm thinking that I can condense this, but I want to make sure that my logic isn't flawed.

The conditional as it stands is as follows:

```
if ((b1 && b2) || (b1 && b2 && !b3))
```

Where `b1`, `b2`, and `b3` are `boolean` values of course.

If I'm reading this right, the following is true:

- If `b1 && b2` is `true` then the `rhs` of the `or` condition will not be considered.
- If `b1 && b2` is `false` then the `rhs` of the `or` condition can not be `true`.

Therefore, the `rhs` of the condition is completely unnecessary and serves no purpose, and it can be condensed into the following:

```
if (b1 && b2)
```

**Is my logic true, or am I missing something?**

PS> If someone has a suggestion for a better title, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since both conditions require `b1` and `b2` to be true:

```
if ((b1 && b2) // b1 and b2 are true
     ||
    (b1 && b2 && !b3)) //b1 and b2 are true *and* b3 is false
```

If `b3` is true, the first condition is satisfied.  If `b3` is false, the second condition is satisfied.  Thus, the value of `b3` is irrelevant.  Plus, as you mentioned, if either `b1` or `b2` are false, the second condition wouldn't even be evaluated.

The statement is equivalent to:

```
if ((b1 && b2) || (b1 && b2)))
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
if (b1 && b2)
```

Comment: Thanks! This confirms that I'm not crazy...yet.

Comment: This could fail if `b1` or `b2` are in fact expressions which could evaluate differently when called two times. Of course, that would be a horrible idea, I am just mentioning it for completeness.